# Alternate adding a character to the beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a Javascript puzzle. I need to write a function that uses a while loop to add a character to the beginning of string and then on the next loop adds the character to the end of the string and to the beginning on the loop after that. The function takes two parameters a string and a number of characters to add. 
So far I have

```
function padIt(str,n){
  //coding here
    var newStr = "";
    var padding = "*";
    var i = 0;

    while(i<=n){
        if (i%2===0){
          newStr = newStr+padding;
        } else{
          newStr = padding+str;
         }
       i++;
     }
    return newStr;
   }
```

I am passing the first two test cases but it won't work properly for the third time through the loop. Expecting "* * a *" for n = 3 but only getting "*a". It has to be a while loop so I don't know if I am not setting the loop up correctly or if I am messing up the variables. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am totally lost.

Comment: You need to comment/remove your `//newStr+=padding;` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by writing code like below,

```
function padIt(str,n, pad = "*"){
  var left = Math.ceil(n/2), right = n - left;
  return pad.repeat(left) + str + pad.repeat(right);
}
```

And this function would print,

```
console.log("a", 1); // "*a"
console.log("a", 2); // "*a*"
console.log("a", 10); // "*****a*****"
```

Thing need to be read after implementing this code,

- [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: Not a while loop but I think this is definitely how I should use the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment your `newStr+=padding;` line.

Here is the refined code,

```
function padIt(str,n){
  //coding here
  var newStr = "";
  var padding = "*";
  var i = 0;

  while(i<=n){
    i++;
    newStr=padding+str;
    //newStr+=padding;
}

  return newStr;

}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```js
function padIt(str,n){
  while(n>0){
    if(n%2 === 0){
      str = str + '*';
    } else{
      str = '*' + str;
    }
    n--;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).